# How to improve performance this sql of mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, and now I must order table's **A** by **B**'s  count：

**A：**

```
id  | name      | status
--- |-----------|---------
1   |  test     |  1
2   |  this is 2|  1
```

**B：**

```
id | a_id | user_id
---|------|----------
1  | 1    |   12
2  | 1    |   13
3  | 1    |   14
4  | 2    |   12
5  | 2    |   15
```

Now I want to fetch limit 5 of the most users from table **A**:

```
SELECT a.name, b.total
FROM tb_a a
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) total, a_id FROM tb_b GROUP BY a_id) b
ON a.id = b.a_id
WHERE a.status = 1
ORDER BY b.`total` DESC
```

I have created index for `a_id` column in table **B**.

After executed, **explain**:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: a
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <derived2>
         type: ref
possible_keys: <auto_key0>
          key: <auto_key0>
      key_len: 4
          ref: test.a.id
         rows: 2
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: tb_b
         type: index
possible_keys: idx_id
          key: idx_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 7
        Extra: Using index
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I find that the first used **Using temporary; Using filesort**, I know this must be refactored!

But how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need subquery?

Won't this work for you:

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(b.id) as total
FROM tb_a a
INNER JOIN tb_b b ON a.id = b.a_id
WHERE a.status = 1
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY COUNT(b.id) DESC
```

Comment: @light : Glad to hear that :) Then mark the question as answered :)

Comment: But i want know the benefit of using this way. Because now also have `Using temporary; Using filesort`. Not like my sql, there just two result after   explain..

Comment: The main thing is the subquery. Those are delaying execution. Also GROUP BY is a factor. With your example - you were grouping on ALL records of table `tb_b`, where with my suggestion grouping only works with those where `tb_b.id=a.id`. IN other words: subset to be grouped is less... Both of the changes above will make the query faster.